# How to create composite unique constraint on multiple value objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I need to create a unique constraint on multiple fields, and those fields are ValueObjects.

Let's say I have this

```cs
public class MyEntity 
{
   public EntityCode Code {get;set;}
   public SecondaryCode Second {get;set;}
}

public class EntityCode : ValueObject<string>
{
   public string Value {get;set;}
   public string Description {get;set;}
}

public class SecondaryCode: ValueObject<string>
{
   public string Value {get;set;}
   public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

I can create a unique constraint like this

```cs
public class MyEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
{
   ...


   builder.OwnsOne(p => p.Code)
       .HasIndex(p => p.Value)
       .IsUnique()

   ...
}
```

But I would like a composite key and I can't figure out how to do this with value object.
Take a look at this sample, it is not working as I expected

```cs
  builder.OwnsOne(p => p.Code);
  builder.OwnsOne(p => p.Second);

  builder
       .HasIndex(p => new { p.Code.Value, p.Seconde.Value })
       .IsUnique()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A key serves as a `unique identifier` for each entity instance. Most entities in EF have a single key, which maps to the concept of a primary key in relational databases. You can also configure multiple properties to be the key of an entity - this is known as a `composite key`.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    builder.Entity<MyEntity>()
           .HasKey(p => new { p.Code.Value, p.Seconde.Value });
}
```

[Composite keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations) can ***only be configured using the Fluent API***, conventions will never set up a composite key, and you can not use Data Annotations to configure one.

To create this composite primary key with these two columns, override `DbContext.OnModelCreating()`. This method is called when the model for a derived context has been initialized, but before the model has been locked down and used to initialize the context.

```cs
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        // Normal DbContext stuff here
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           builder.Entity<MyEntity>()
           .HasKey(p => new { p.Code.Value, p.Seconde.AnotherValue });
        }
    }
```

after that generate the migration and update database.

Comment: This is actually my bad, I wrote index, but meant key and your sample is not working

Comment: Answer is updated. please recheck now, this must be worked.

Comment: @md-rakib-hasan I don't think it works , Duplicate anonymous type property name 'Value'

Comment: Isn't possible to put it inside an EntityTypeConfiguration<> file instead?

Comment: And also, .IsUnique() cannot be resolved

Comment: no it is not possible with ```EntityTypeConfiguration<>```. and you should change ```value``` property name from any of your models. like ```Value``` in ```EntityCode```  and ```AnotherValue``` in  ```SecondaryCode```

Comment: It seems I was actualy right, to creacte a Unique constraint, it needs to be and IndexBuilder, then HasInde() has to be called.

Comment: I don't want to rename my properties because the implementation of another object has the same name, it's not a suitable solution